# Python - Errno 13 Permission denied when trying to copy files

Tags: python, file-copying

I am attempting to make a program in Python that copies the files on my flash drive (letter D:) to a folder on my hard drive but am getting a *PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'D:'*.

The problematic part of my code is as follows:

```
# Copy files to folder in current directory
def copy():
    source = getsource()

    if source != "failure":

        copyfile(source, createfolder())
        wait("Successfully backup up drive"
             "\nPress 'Enter' to exit the program")

    else:
        wait("No USB drive was detected"
             "\nPress 'Enter' to exit")

# Create a folder in current directory w/ date and time
def createfolder():
    name = strftime("%a, %b %d, %Y, %H.%M.%S", gmtime())
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    new_folder = dir_path + "\\" + name
    os.makedirs(new_folder)

return new_folder
```

Everything seems to run fine until the *copyfile()* function runs, where it returns the error.
I tried replacing *getsource()* with the destination of the file instead and it returned the same permission error except for the *new_folder* directory instead.

I have read several other posts but none of them seem to be relevant to my case. I have full admin permissions to both locations as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this might be happening because you may be trying to open the `D:` directory as if it was a file.

Comment: @Harrison Is there a way that I would be able to open the directory so that I could copy the files inside of it?

Comment: Yes i'll post an answer.

Comment: @Harrison Thank you!

Comment: There you go. That should be enough for you to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in my comment above, it seems as if you're trying to open the directory, `D:`, as if it was a file, and that's not going to work because it's not a file, it's a directory.

What you can do is use `os.listdir()` to list all of the files within your desired directory, and then use `shutil.copy()` to copy the files as you please.

Here is the documentation for each of those:

[os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) (You will be passing the full file path to this function)

[shutil.copy()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) (You will be passing each file to this function)

Essentially you would store all of the files in the directory in a variable, such as `all_the_files = os.listdir(/path/to/file)`, then loop through `all_the_files` by doing something like `for each_file in all_the_files:` and then use `shutil.copy()` to copy them as you please.

Comment: So, that worked perfectly but now I am still getting the same error for the folder which I'm trying to copy to... Any suggestions?

Comment: Just looked at the documentation and found that the correct shutil method is  `copy()`, to copy to a specific directory. `copyfile()` copies the contents of a file to another file. Thanks again for the answer!

Comment: @QuintonShips Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to copy an entire directory and its contents, then `shutil.copytree(source, destination)` can be used.